# How to get Audio and Video file total time duration using python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My scenario I am trying to get `Audio` and `Video` file total `duration` with `“HH:MM:SS”` format using `python`. I tried by using `ffmpeg` but its not comfortable because I am coding inside `AWS Lambda`, So it is very hard to add huge size of library. Please suggest and provide some lines of code regarding my question.

```
import os
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i samplefile.mp3 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk "{print $2}" | tr -d ,'
os.system(cmd)
print os.system(cmd)
```

Above lines of code I used, it will work only in local not `AWS lambda` because we don’t have library compatibility. So please suggest some other idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the `ffmpy` package at https://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. could you please tell me how to do for time duration. Can I get total time duration by using ffmpy...@shellwhale